# How to improve okhttp3 performance during cold startup

Tags: android, performance, ssl, okhttp

I've run nimbledroid profiler and I've came across many ocurrences following method chain:

[image: systemDefaultTrustManager]

Is there a way to cache or bypass `systemDefaultTrustManager`?

Comment: "Is there a way to cache" -- cache the `OkHttpClient` instance. "I've came across many ocurrences following method chain" -- then stop creating many `OkHttpClient` instances.

Comment: @CommonsWare Many libraries are creating in internally, so those calls are piling up... Also maybe there is a way not to call system default trust manager...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've came across many ocurrences following method chain

You are creating many instances of `OkHttpClient`.

> Is there a way to cache or bypass systemDefaultTrustManager?

Cache the instance of `OkHttpClient`.

> Many libraries are creating in internally, so those calls are piling up

Then do one of the following:

- Find a means of supplying an `OkHttpClient` instance to the library, so that you can create the `OkHttpClient` instance yourself and cache it, or
- Work with the developers of that library to provide a means of supplying an `OkHttpClient` instance to the library, or
- Fork the library, if it is open source, and add a means of supplying an `OkHttpClient` instance to the library, or
- Switch to a different library